# Subscribe to an event on Composer v0.19.12

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm new to Hyperledger Composer. I already finished the composer tutorial. I can get and post using an external node script via REST API. I want to write a script to listen to events on the blockchain from a remote machine but don't know how to do it. I appreciate if you please could help.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below Steps 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/publishing-events.html
that use wscat lib to test event and change localhost to the IP where you Rest server will publish events

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the answer. I already tried that and it works. However, I want to subscribe to the events that are emitted by the peers, not the ones that are relayed by the REST server. Do you know any way of doing that?

Comment: what is the events you want to subscribe that raised by peer ? you mean that you didn't emit events from your code ?

Comment: Hi, they're the same events but I want to get it directly from the peers, not from the REST server. I was able to emit events and receive them through a self-built script from the REST server.